# What's this 3 x 2, 6-pin + latch connector's name?

Tags: power-supply, identification, connector

I couldn't get the wires out of this connector and I bent it too much. I'm trying to find a replacement on the internet.

It's a rather common power connector (this one is from an electric motor), but I don't know how to search for it on the internet ("6-pin plug" yields a variety of wrong results, plus there are some square plugs and some round plugs in this one; they don't match.

What is this connector's name exactly? I might also need the metal "grafts" inside these 6 pins (I don't know how to search for them either).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family/minifit_power_connector_solutions

Comment: https://www.mouser.pl/ProductDetail/Molex/39-01-2065?qs=zXrbR4Jv0OdMj1nvDbeWOA%3D%3D

Comment: There’s a special pin removal tool for those, I bought mine for 30$ on digikey. Tweezers don’t really cut it.

Comment: Make sure to measure the pitch, there are 2 versions, 4.8mm and 4.2mm pitch.

Answer (score 3):

My [connector identification utility](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=partitioned_shroud_latch_mini_fit_jr_conn) tells me that it's a connector made by multiple companies:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- Adam tech - DMF
- Adam tech - DMF + DMH
- Amphenol - Minitek Pwr 4.2
- CNC Tech - 4282 + 4281
- Cvilux - CP-012 CP-013 CP-014 + CP-011
- Molex - 5025
- Molex - Mini-Fit Jr
- TE - AMP-DUAC
- TE - VAL-U-LOK
- Wurth - WR-MPC4

The most common of them is the Molex Minifit JR, which you can find here: https://www.digikey.com/short/rn5135nz, including [this one](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0039012060/61379).

[image: Minifit JR]

{Digikey}